# Vote counter in html/js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I'm fairly new to programming and have been learning HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I'm working on a project involving the upcoming election where a users presses a button (using `<form>` in html) to vote for a candidate. What I'm having an issue doing is relaying the results. Using either javascript or html, how would I be able to track the amount of times each button is pressed and relay the information later in the webpage that says the number of votes for each candidate and the total number of votes.

**EDIT** I've messed around with the code a little and here is my current javascript file, I set the program to tell you who you voted for in an alert() message, but the name of the candidate isn't showing up properly...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>     
<head>         
<meta charset="utf-8" >         
<title>Election</title>
</head>
<body>   
<center>
<h1>2016 Presidential Election</h1>
<h2>Vote Here</h2>
<form>
<button type="button" onclick="clicksubmit()">Click to vote for Trump</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clicksubmit()">Click to vote for Hillary</button>
</form>
<h3>Results:</h3>
</center>
<script src="election.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

JS:

```
function clicksubmit(){

    var votehillary = document.getElementById('hillary'); 
    alert("You voted for "+ votehillary);
    var votetrump = document.getElementById('trump'); 
    alert("You voted for "+ votetrump);

}
```

Comment: show us what you have done so far

Comment: You need to show us your code. So that we can see where the error is if there is.

Comment: I will upload the code in a minute, I need to retrieve it from my laptop. Its more of a lack of knowledge then an error, but ill upload what i have.

Comment: In order to tally counts from multiple users and then feed them back to visitors you need to store data on the server side, which is going to be beyond your current skill set.

Comment: I was under the impression that I need to use something like "document.getElementById()". All it needs to do is actively display the number of times the button has been clicked. It should reset every time the page is reloaded, its supposed to be much more simple then I think you realize.

Comment: where is the javascript code ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must **include the shortest code** necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I dont have any right now, that the issue im having, I dont know what to put in to display the counter.

Comment: You will need some server side programming. Else, all the changes will be lost as soon as you refresh the page. If that's not an issue and you want all the users to vote at the same device, you can use Ole's answer.

Answer (score 0):

To count your button clicks you can declare a variable for each candidate and increment them on each click. To do so, you need to change your button elements and your result header:

```
<h3 id="results">
  total: 0
  trump: 0
  hillary: 0
</h3>
<button type="button" id="trump-button">Click to vote for Trump</button>
<button type="button" id="hillary-button">Click to vote for Hillary</button>
```

In your election.js file you can fetch each button and apply a onClick event to them, incrementing a variable declared when the page is loaded:

```
var trump = 0;
var hillary = 0;

function refreshResults () {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  results.innerHTML = 'total: ' + (trump + hillary);
  results.innerHTML += '<br />trump: ' + trump;
  results.innerHTML += '<br />hillary: ' + hillary;
}

document.getElementById('trump-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  trump++;
  refreshResults();
});

document.getElementById('hillary-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  hillary++;
  refreshResults();
});
```

Comment: However, this code works but it is not well written and can be improved by many ways.

Comment: The final product produced what I was looking for. Might I ask what .addEventListener and refreshResults() do?

Comment: addEventListener is a method that every DOM node has. With this method you can apply a function to a event like click, so the function is called when the DOM node is clicked.

refreshResults calls the function that is created in line 4. It sets the innerHTML of the results header.